# Parse Server PHP SDK - Can't Resolve HerokuApp URL

Tags: php, curl, heroku, parse-platform, dns

I'm trying to implement the Parse SDK to my project. However, I'm having several issues as I try to initialize the client and make a test request. It seems that the cURL methods of ParseClient cannot resolve the URL of my heroku server. The following is my code :

```
<?php
define( 'PARSE_SDK_DIR', 'src/Parse/' );
require 'autoload.php';

use Parse\ParseClient as ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseObject as ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery as ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseCloud;


$app_id = '';
$master_key = '';
$rest_key = '';


try{
    ParseClient::initialize($app_id,$rest_key,$master_key);
    echo "Parse Client Initialized. <br>";
    ParseClient::setServerURL('https://myapp.herokuapp.com:1337','parse');
    echo "Parse Client URL Set. <br>";
    $query = new ParseQuery("_User");
    $object = $query->get("003D6yZoyb");
    echo $object->getObjectId();
    }
catch (Parse\ParseException $ex){
    echo "Error while sending query.<br>";
    echo "Error code ".$ex->getCode().": ".$ex->getMessage()."<br>";
    }

try{
$testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
$testObject->set("foo", "bar");
$testObject->save();
echo $testObject->getObjectId();
}
catch (Parse\ParseException $ex){
    echo "Error while saving object<br>";
    echo "Error code ".$ex->getCode().": ".$ex->getMessage()."<br>";
}
?>
```

And with this code, I get the following output :

```
Parse Client Initialized. 
Parse Client URL Set. 
Error while sending query.
Error code 6: Couldn't resolve host 'myapp.herokuapp.com'
Error while saving object
Error code 6: Couldn't resolve host 'myapp.herokuapp.com'
```

However, if I change the port to 443, it gives another error ( 0 - Unauthorized). I know for a fact that the server is working and if I run the following command on the terminal it works :

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appid" \
  -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: masterkey" \
  https://myapp.herokuapp.com:443/parse/classes/_User
```

If anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong I would really appreciate it if you could let me know!

Thanks!

**EDIT**: One more thing, when I ping my server I get :

```
ping: cannot resolve https://myapp.herokuapp.com/: Unknown host
```

Yet, the CURL from the terminal still works.

Comment: Glad you got your error checking sorted out. "Couldn't resolve host" is a pretty clear error. Sounds like you might have DNS problems.

Comment: Do you know what that might be? Because, again, the curl call works from the terminal so I'm kind of confused @miken32